# Why model form is not opening on anchor <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a icon of plus + sign which is supposed to open a modal form on click 
but here modal form is not opening.

```
<td>
    <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
    </p> 
</td>
```

Above code represent + sign and click on it.

Model Form code is below:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
     </div>

     <div class="modal-body">
         <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong with it. I am unable to find it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap.js library included?  I believe it's required for `data-toggle` to work.

Comment: thanx you are right I missed  one bootstrap js library.

Comment: Sweet, happy to help.  I guess I'll promote my comment to an answer for closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bootstrap.js` library needs to be included in order for `data-toggle` to work.